# Cannot recognize CRLF on Linux Java

Tags: java, linux, sockets, encoding, stream

I'm reading a byte array from a socket and converting it to a string with:

```
output = new String(input, "UTF-8");
```

then trying to remove the CRLF with:

```
output.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");
```

but still when I inspect a little further:

```
Read ('hi') 4 bytes

Char value
104
105
13 <- CR
10 <- LF
0
0
0
...
```

Any suggestions? I've tried changing the encoding and removing CR or LF, even checking for 10 or 13 in the byte array and changing it to 0 but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
output = output.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");
```